Trying to create a test cookie for an HTML web but not working
I'm trying to store "cookies" on a webpage. My problem comes to the point of actually storing them where it seems that they aren't being stored.
I'm using Brave as my browser but also tried on Chrome and Edge. My current code is the following:
setCookie = (cName, cValue, expDays) => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = `${cName}=${cValue}; ${expires}; path=/`;
    console.log("asd");
}

getCookie = (cName) => {
    const cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const cArr = cDecoded.split(";");
    let value;
    cArr.forEach(val => {
        if (val.trim().indexOf(cName + "=") == 0) {
            value = val.substring(cName.length + 1).trim();
        }
    });
    return value;
}

document.querySelector("#cookies-btnA").addEventListener("click", () => {
    setCookie("cookie_accepted", "true", 30);
    document.querySelector("#cookies").style.display = "none";
});

cookieMessage = () => {
    if (getCookie("cookie_accepted") === "true") {
        document.querySelector("#cookies").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#cookies").style.display = "block";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", cookieMessage);

and this is the HTML it's refering to:
<div id="cookies">
        <div class="cookieContainer">
            <div class="cookieSubContainer" `>
                <h1> Cookies </h1>
                <p>
                    This site uses cookies to assure a better experience
                    <a href="cookies.html">cookies policies</a><br>
                    <button id="cookies-btnA">Accept</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

The way i'd like it to work is: the cookies thing covers the main screen and then once you click on any button it will store all cookies this menu will then hide and not show again even if you refresh the webpage, currently it properly covers the screen and then hides once clicking, but if I refresh the web it appears again.
This is the CSS:
.cookieContainer {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#cookies {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.cookieSubContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(179, 179, 176);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cookieSubContainer h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cookieSubContainer p {
  text-align: center;
}

.cookieSubContainer a {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cookieSubContainer button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
}

I tried different ways of creating the setCookie function on my JavaScript but nothing seemed to work properly, I know it enters the function because whenever you click on it the console.log() prints properly, also there is an "undefined" cookie that appears if you also do a console.log to the document.cookie = ... line
I tried with different videos, the current one I think belongs to a channel named bro code

video 1
bro code video


Cookies are a server thing, where the server sends you a label (that gets automatically sent back to the server with future requests) for the purpose of maintaining who you are, what's in your order basket, etc.

@ControlAltDel Cookies can also be set in the client.

But now you can use localStorage instead of cookies for persistent client data.

If you look at the list of cookies in DevTools, do you see this one?

@Barmar RE: client initiated cookies - These seem to have limited functionality - they only work if the server accepts them, correct? And now that there's localstorage, I don't understand what this would offer beyond a regular GET or POST request. Can you enlighten me/us? I am not trying to challenge you so much as figure out what these are good for

@ControlAltDel client-set cookies don't depend on the server at all. They do get sent to the server just like server cookies. You can use localStorage now, but that hasn't always existed, and AFAIK there's no plan yet to deprecate them, even though there's overlap in functionality.

The reason for getting 'undefined' is because there are no cookies set. In order to set cookies in the client side, you need your website running on a remote host.
If your website is stored in a localhost (in your PC), most browsers won't let you to set cookies.
But Firefox still lets you set cookies in the localhost.
You may try Firefox if you're running this in your localhost.
Or you can try running this on a remote host instead.
